# Half-Even Rounding - 265.335 rounding to 2 digits gives 265.33 but should be 265.34?

Tags: java, c#

I'm working on a bit of code where I'm implementing half-even rounding. I've been using this post ([How to round a number to n decimal places in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java)) as a guide and am running tests using the code below on an online Java compiler:

```
// Java code
public static void main(String []args){
        String precisionString = "#.##";
        double localValue = 265.335;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(precisionString);
        df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
        System.out.println(Double.parseDouble(df.format(localValue)));    
     }
```

It works fine for most test values, but for the value 265.335, rounding to 2 decimal places returns 265.33 when it should be 265.34.

I tested this out on an online C# compiler and got similar results (C# equivalent below), so I'm thinking this isn't a language bug but rather something to do with how the numbers are being read in binary. I'm not able to figure out exactly what/where the problem is though..

```
// C# code
public static void Main()
    {
        double a = 265.335;
        var rounded = Math.Round(a, 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven);
        Console.WriteLine(rounded);
    }
```

Thoughts ?

Comment: `a = 235.335` doesn't actually set `a` to `235.335`.  It sets it to the nearest number that has a precise `double` representation.

Comment: ... which according to [this online calculator](https://www.exploringbinary.com/floating-point-converter/) happens to be `265.33499999999997953636921010911464691162109375`, which is why it got rounded down.

Comment: In C# just use [decimal type](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.decimal?view=net-7.0#remarks) and It would get rounded to 235.34

Comment: You can also do `new BigDecimal(265.335)` in Java to see the real floating-point representation of `265.335`. That will match to the one from the above online calculator. You can also use `var bd = BigDecimal.valueOf(265.335); df.format(bd)`, which will achieve you goal. For details, you can refer to javadoc of `BigDecimal` methods I've outlined here.